# How to create button action on cell click in a collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uicollectionview

Actually I have taken a two collection view controllers. In first collection view controller iIhave passed array of images.on the click of the one image ,i want to display another collection view controller.how to do this...please suggest me .

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];

recipeImages = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"angry_birds_cake.jpg", @"creme_brelee.jpg", @"egg_benedict.jpg", @"full_breakfast.jpg", @"green_tea.jpg", @"ham_and_cheese_panini.jpg", @"ham_and_egg_sandwich.jpg", @"hamburger.jpg", @"instant_noodle_with_egg.jpg", nil];
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return recipeImages.count;
}

- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

}
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";

UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:identifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

UIImageView *recipeImageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
recipeImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[recipeImages objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"photo-frame.png"]];
for (UIView *view in cell.subviews) {
    if ([view isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
        [view removeFromSuperview];
    }
}


UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5, 0, 150, 170)];//Set the frame as per your requirement.
label.font=[UIFont systemFontOfSize:10];

[label setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]]];
[cell addSubview:label];
//NSLog(@"hiiiii");


return cell;
```

}

Comment: After clicking an image, you want to show another collection view controller in different view controller? You just need push new view controller which contains UICollectionView like you do.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to show the second collection view in another view controller, you would just push the view controller with the collection view in it in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`.

If you would like to show the second collection view in the same view controller, you could create two collection views and set the second to hidden. Then in `didSelectItemAtIndexPath:`, you could set the second collection view to show and the first to hidden. This would be done through `collectionView.hidden = YES or NO.`

Answer (score 1):

For displaying another `UICollectionViewController` on the click of an item in another `UICollectionViewController`, you have to use the `didSelectItemAtIndexPath` function. You can do it like this :

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    int itemNo = (int)[indexPath row]+1;
    CollectionViewCell *selectedCell = (CollectionViewCell*)[collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    switch (itemNo) {
        case 1:
        {
             //perform segue to another UICollectionViewController.
        }
        case 2:
        {
             //perform segue to another UICollectionViewController.
        }
        .
        .
        .
     }
}
```

Here `itemNo` is the item(Cell), that is clicked from the Collection View. If you have to redirect to the same `UICollectionViewController` for all item clicks, the you won't be needing the `switch` and you can do it directly with Segue.

Hope this helps.